# UDF is not working until pressing enter key in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

If someone pasted text in a data validation dropdown and it doesn't match with the Data validation list, I'm highlighting the cell by using a red font color `range..Font.Color = vbRed`

I'm using the below UDF as an Excel formula to find out the font color of the cell, but this UDF is not calling until I select the cell, go to formula bar and hit enter.

```
Function GetColorText(pRange As Range) As Integer

Application.Volatile

    If IsEmpty(pRange) Then Exit Function

    Dim xOut As Integer

    xOut = pRange.Font.ColorIndex

    GetColorText = xOut

End Function
```

Comment: Try adding `Application.Volatile` before any other line in your UDF [Application.Volatile method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile)

Comment: application.volatile is for recalculation, but my code is to identify the text color in a cell. I have added this coe whether it iwill solve my issue. but volatile also not resolved my issue.

Comment: Tested by adding volatile before prange.font.colorindex. not resolved my issue

Comment: Is calculation set to Automatic?

Comment: I see ypur point now. There is no event that catches only if the font color changed. VBA will detect if the value changes but if you just change format, it will not be detected, and your UDF will not be triggered. Maybe you should consider forcing recalculation other way.

Comment: I recommend to stay away from using formattings like colors to transport actual information. Colors should be the **result** of an information (just for the purpose to illustrate). So use the data validation logic (or what ever makes the color change) based on your actual information in your UDF instead of the color itself. Use the color only for illustrating.

Comment: Sadly, there is no native event to capture a cell color change. No events... No Formula... No UDF. Having said that, you CAN trap a cell color change in a cell but that involves lot of code which involves a class module to monitor previous and current color. So basically the moment the color changes, the UDF has to be called from that code

Comment: [Here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/capturing-cell-color-change-in-vba.574405/) is an example of what I am talking about.

Comment: @norie - the calculation is set to automatic in Excel options

Comment: The advice given by @Pᴇʜ is the best approach. Stop using colours to transport information. It is bad practice. Use Excel's [Conditional Formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) feature to apply formatting to cells.